# Aeotec Trisensor undefined behavior

Tags: sensors

I've been using a few of the device of the same model for several months. While they've been working great, one of them recently started showing strange behavior that I cannot find defined in the user manual. [See the video I took and uploaded on my Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IkxghdSaz7BlhwBv1JMGbUHdR_ZVvgua/view?usp=sharing).

- It seems to me the light pattern is undefined in the manual (Some red and many white bli).
- Triggered factory reset (hold a button for 15 seconds) didn't seem to change the behavior.
- It used to be included in Z-Wave gateway (`Home Assistant` via `ZWaveJS`) and reporting well, but not anymore. The device doesn't even seem to trigger inclusion mode.

Anyone has ideas of what's going on? I want to see if it's malfunctioning (so that I should ask the manufacturer's support).

- [Product official page (aeotec.com)](https://aeotec.com/products/aeotec-tri-sensor/)
- [User manual (aeotec.freshdesk.com, linked from the product official page)](https://aeotec.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/6000195459-trisensor-user-guide-)

Comment: yes it is malfunctioning ... call tech support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @jsotola for patting my shoulder to talk to the manufacturer, who's also confirming (final confirmation going on) that this is malfunctioning.